# How to plot a boxplot using aggregates in plotly?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I need to plot a series of boxplots, based on results of numerical air quality model. Since this is a significant amount of data, I trigger calculation of aggregates (min, max, quartiles, etc.) every time when new model results become ready and store them in PostgreSQL. For visualization purpose I load the aggregates into pandas and I plot them using dash. I am able to plot line plots of timeseries, however I would like to get something like [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhHi4.png), but also interactive.

As I went through plotly examples, it looks like it always require the raw data for ploting boxplots ( https://plot.ly/python/box-plots/#basic-box-plot ). I really enjoy the concept of presentation and logic separation. Is it possible to get a plotly box plot based on aggregated data?

Comment: this work with Javascript but should probably work with Python as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944430/ploting-box-plot-from-statistical-summary-data/53957772#53957772

Comment: See updated answer for a solution using Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide your aggreate values to a Plotly boxplot in Python by providing it in the following format:

```
plotly.graph_objs.Box(y=[val_min, 
                         val_lower_box, 
                         val_lower_box, 
                         val_median, 
                         val_upper_box, 
                         val_upper_box, 
                         val_max])
```

e.g.

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

val_min = 1
val_lower_box = 2
val_median = 3
val_upper_box = 4.5
val_max = 6

box_plot = plotly.graph_objs.Box(y=[val_min, 
                                    val_lower_box, 
                                    val_lower_box, 
                                    val_median, 
                                    val_upper_box, 
                                    val_upper_box, 
                                    val_max])
plotly.offline.iplot([box_plot])
```

gives you

[image]

Comment: Thank you Maximillian. That's a smart walkaround.